# Getting nearby localities from lat long using Google place API

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using google place API i.e

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.7167,73.0667&radius=500&type=funeral_home&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDN1QX-gWUR-mIYo_D21PNFLHHpNQkIkGU
```

Above link gives me all the nearby locations of particular type. i.e types=food. now i will get all the cafes and restaurants nearby with their respective addresses. Is there anyway that can give me only areas or localities nearby my coordinates (lat, long)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your api key is working properly?

Comment: yes it is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar usecase too. I did not have a way to do it using google maps api. But, you can try getting geometry (lat, lng) from Autocomplete getPlaces() and use geonames.org API to get nearby sublocalities giving lat, lng and radius

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=13.041703&lng=80.251943&radius=5&username=demo

This worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Arun if you can give  the latitude and longitude value in

```
 //MAP

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;        

    //if you want to use the GET for getting response for MAP from that URL,you can use this

    coordinate.latitude = [[[Arrresult objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"]doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude =[[[Arrresult objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"longitude"]doubleValue] ;

    //or if you want to see the exact or nearest location just give like this 
    coordinate.latitude = @"33.7167";
    coordinate.longitude =@"73.0667";

    region.center = coordinate;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;
    region.span = span;
    myannotation *annotation = [[myannotation alloc]init];
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
    [annotation setTitles:areastring :countrystring];

    [map setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [map addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: I dont want to show map. I just need all the areas nearby my coordinates. Let me check what your code is doing!

Comment: what happened? did you get that?

Comment: No! I don't want this.