# Getting nearby places limited by category with Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have the GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces pods installed, and I need to give them a lat/long and get back a list of nearby places in a small radius, but the list should be limited by type.

So, a user touches a position on the map. I send up that lat/long and a list of types with the sdk and I get back an array of places that are most likely the place they touched.

I see two things:

GooglePlacePicker - I don't want to use this because it's more than I need and forces me to push a new view.

currentPlace method - I don't see any way to force this to look at a specific lat/long, only the device's current location.

How do I accomplish what I want to do here? I know there has to be a way, but I'm not seeing it in the Google SDK references anywhere.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830321/getting-nearby-localities-from-lat-long-using-google-place-api

Comment: @JasmeetKaur I don't see a solution in that answer that satisfies what I'm looking for, only the same questions unanswered.